# Can we replace PHP language constructs with our own?

Tags: php

PHP allows you to replace or even re-name PHP's built-in functions using functions such as
[`override_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) and [`rename_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename-function.php).

Can we override the PHP's language constructs like `echo` and `eval`?

Comment: why not try it? just create a blank php doc and check if this is possible

Comment: because i dont know how to do it :)

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: i just wanted to know if this is possible or not. no hard and fast need at this point of time though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's possible : it's a language **construct**, which means something that's more than "integrated" to the language : it's really a "part" of the language.

Answer (score 3):

No, this isn't possible within PHP.

The only way I can think of would be to create a custom handler for PHP files (in apache or whichever web server you're using).

The custom handler could then search and replace core language constructs with functions of your own, before being passed to the real PHP handler.