# PHP - Change of text with regex

Tags: php, html, regex, string, preg-replace

I know that this question has been asked a lot of times, but I have searched on the site and I have not found a solution.

I am trying to "override" the function `echo` of php, my goal is to filter all the php output in all the files.
I need to replace the html text with the following directives:

```
echo"SOME STRING"
```

with:

```
echo_custom("SOME STRING")
```

and

```
echo("SOME STRING")
```

with

```
echo_custom("SOME STRING)
```

Comment: Wouldn't be more practical to replace the `echo()` function in your system with `echo_custom` and call `echo()` inside that one after you do your filter? If you override echo you will have to run another function to print the information.

Comment: So... you're *not* actually trying to override the `echo` *"function"* (\*ahem\* language construct to be pedantic) just *grep* the codebase to replace it with a custom function?

Comment: @Rafael , i have put the word override between the quotation marks because `echo` is not a function, but a language statement. It cannot be redefined. 
Your answer is exactly what i am trying to do, but i need to replace hundreds of files so i need to grep the codebase to replace it with a custom function as he has written @CD001

@B001ᛦ I hope that your answer is not sarcastic, for "this question" i mean a question related to Regex function.

Comment: @Daniele, I'm against using sarcasm unless provoked. And you are right, I tend to ignore this fact but it's important to remember. Though, you can rename a function from php, but not a language construct, so, with that in mind, there is a workaround as suggested by Dave in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873291/can-we-replace-php-language-constructs-with-our-own

Comment: @Rafael I was not referring to you when i said "I hope that your answer is not sarcastic", anyway thank you for your  contribution and for the link posted with the workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do the job:

```
$in = <<<EOD
echo"SOME STRING"
echo("SOME STRING")
echo"SOME STRING";
echo("SOME STRING");
EOD;


$out = preg_replace('/echo\(?(.+?)\)?(?=;|\R)/', 'echo_custom($1)', $in);
echo $out,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
echo_custom("SOME STRING")
echo_custom("SOME STRING")
echo_custom("SOME STRING");
echo_custom("SOME STRING");
```

**Explanation:**

```
echo        : literally
\(?         : optional opening parenhesis
(           : start group 1
    .+?     : 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
)           : end group 1
\)?         : optional closing parenthesis
(?=         : positive lookahead, make sure we have after
    ;       : semicolon
  |         : OR
    \R      : any kind of linebreak
)           : end lookahead
```